# How can I get google sheets to ignore single quotation marks such as with a value like (4'9")?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have a "survey gizmo" survey that will output a height measurement such as 4'9" into a google spreadsheet. Survey takers will choose their height from a drop down menu. I want to keep the ft'in" format for my user interface because this is the easiest way for people to choose their height.

However, spreadsheets don't like it when they see single " and ' marks. I want to make a function that will read values like (4'9") and convert them to inches (57) in another column so that I can use that numerical value in another equation.

I can't figure out how to read 4'9" into a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function should work in both Excel and Google Sheets:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("'", A1)-1)*12+(MID(A1,FIND("'", A1)+1, FIND("""", A1)-FIND("'", A1)-1))
```

Tested it with `6'2"` and `12'11"`

Comment: Just to be clear, LEFT(A1, FIND("'", A1)-1) finds the single ' and then uses everything (-1) or everything to the left of '? And then the MID function finds ', inputs everything between ' and "?

Comment: @lprater1 - Yes. `LEFT(A1,FIND("'", A1)-1) * 12` takes everything to the left of the first apostrophe and multiplies it by 12. Then the rest of the formula takes everything in between the apostrophe and the quote and adds that to our first part.